# How to execute animations on Activity creation?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, fragment

I'm trying to execute animations when the user enters an activity,
but since I'm calling the animation from onCreate() it's laggy...

Already tried onCreate, onStart and onResume. Any ideas on when/how to start animations when entering activitys?

My code:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    Animation slide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slidedown);
    slider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    slider.startAnimation(slide);
    ....
}
```

Comment: I doubt the reason your animation is laggy is because you're calling it from onCreate. There is likely another reason for the lag you're seeing. Are you running on an emulator? If not, how powerful is the device you're using? How many animations are you trying to execute?

Comment: I'm using my Galaxy S4 i9500 and this animation is being executed also on onClick() and it's smooth

Answer (score 0):

Wait until layout has completed before you start the animation. In this code `view` is the root view of your activity:

```
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @TargetApi(16)
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Start animation here

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            else
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Start the animation in onWindowFocusChanged()

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
   super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
   if (hasFocus)
      //start animation here
}
```